# Find & Replace in Dreamweaver using regex

Tags: html

I've checked a number of the previous questions regarding Dreamweaver but I just can't find one that works for me.

I have the following HTML in hundreds of pages:

```
Muslimgauze information.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Bryn Jones, Muslimgauze, E.g Oblique Graph, 3rd Stone, ant-zen, Aqurellist, Arka Sound, Athanor, Gulf Between Us">
<link rel="stylesheet"
```

The tag `meta name="keyword"` contains any number of different text items.

I want to be able to remove the whole `meta name="keywords"` section and just leave the following:

```
Muslimgauze information.">
<link rel="stylesheet"
```

I've tried all kinds of expressions but just can't seem to get any to work properly.

Any thoughts/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Terry

Answer (score 0):

The regex is quite easy : you need to delete a tag starting with `<meta name="keywords"` and ending with `>` with whatever characters between the start and the end so the regex is :

`^<meta name="keywords" .*>$` (`^` and `$` are matching line start and end)

https://regex101.com/r/yA3dLu/1